# Calculating $A^{80}$ for conditions on $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $A \in \mathbb{C}_{4x4}$ be a matrix fulfills the next conditions -
>
> **1)** $trace(A) = 0$, **2)** $|A-iI| = 0$, **3)** $rank(A-I) = 3$, **4)** $Av=-v$ for some $v \not= 0.$
>
> Calculate $A^{80}.$

**Attempt -**

From the 2nd conditions i can say that $i$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, from the 3rd conditions i can conclude that $1$ is an eigenvalue of A, and from the 4th+1st conditions $-1,-i$ are also eigenvalues.

So $A$ is diagonalizable $\implies A = PDP^{-1}$ for some $P$ and $D = diag(1,-1,i,-i)$.

Can i just say that $A^{80} = diag(1, 1, -1 ,1)$, do i even need $P$ and $P^{-1}$ ?

**Thank you !**

Comment: No, $A^{80} = I$.  Note that $1, -1, i, -i$ are all fourth roots of $1$,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned, there are $4$ distinct eigenvalues for this matrix, so that we can find a transformation $P$ with 
$$ A=PDP^{-1}$$
and $D$ a diagonal matrix, with diagonal entries $1,-1,i,-i$. Then
$$A^{n}=\underbrace{(PDP^{-1})\cdots(PDP^{-1})}_{n\:\text{times}}=PD^nP^{-1}.$$
Now, $D^{80}=I_n$, where $I_n$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix. So, we have that 
$$ A^{80}=PI_nP^{-1}=I_n.$$
So, $A^{80}=I_n$.

Comment: Interesting, why the $P$ matrices have no impact on my calculation ?

Comment: Well, the main observation is that $(PDP^{-1})(PDP^{-1})=(PD)(P^{-1}P)(DP^{-1})=PD^2P^{-1}$. By induction $A^n=PD^n P^{-1}$. From there, it's easy to see that $D^{80}=I_n$, and so $PD^{80}P^{-1}=PI_nP^{-1}=PP^{-1}I_n=I_n$.

Comment: Silly me, that is obvious. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $(x-1)(x+1)(x-i)(x+i)=x^4-1$ and so $A^4=I$. Therefore, $A^{80}=(A^4)^{20}=I$.